Optimizing Convolution Layer on GPU with Torch Tensors
Problem
With the below toy script, I am getting worse results on the GPU than the CPU. I am fairly new to GPU programming, so I'm not sure how to even debug. From my limited research, convolution is something that should be able to be greatly sped up by the GPU so I'm guessing I'm doing something wrong. Is the bottleneck data being sent to and from the GPU?
import timeit

import numpy as np
import torch

def to_torch(x, device):
    if x.dtype == 'float64':
        x = x.astype('float32')
    return torch.from_numpy(x).to(device)

def min_max_normalize(x):
    min_val = torch.min(x)
    max_val = torch.max(x)
    return (x - min_val) / (max_val - min_val)

def test_device(device):
    conv1_weights = to_torch(np.random.randn(3, 3), device)
    conv1_bias = to_torch(np.zeros((415, 415)), device)

    def work():
        data = to_torch(np.random.randn(397, 397), device)
        data = min_max_normalize(data)
        output_height = data.shape[0] - conv1_weights.shape[0] + 1
        output_width = data.shape[1] - conv1_weights.shape[1] + 1
        output = to_torch(np.zeros((output_height, output_width)), device)
        for i in range(output_height):
            for j in range(output_width):
                output[i, j] = torch.sum(data[i:i+conv1_weights.shape[0], j:j+conv1_weights.shape[1]] * conv1_weights)

        output += conv1_bias[:output_height, :output_width]

    return timeit.timeit(work, number=5)

print(test_device("cpu"))
print(test_device("mps"))

which outputs:
4.249846041202545
51.15217095799744

As you can see, the GPU computation is over 10 times slower. Am I using the torch tensors incorrectly?

As written, this is going to require a trip between the CPU and GPU for every pixel of output in your image. That seems like it would be slow. Have you considered using conv2d instead?

Unfortunately this is a school assignment, and we are tasked with constructing and implementing the network ourselves.  So even though output is assigned to the GPU, the assignment back to output[i, j] = ... is requiring a trip between CPU and GPU?

Right. If it's a school assignment, what are the constraints? Do they specifically want you to do this on the GPU, or with torch? Are there parts of torch you're not allowed to use?

We do not HAVE to use the GPU, but we chose a dataset where we NEED the GPU in order to finish on time with good enough results (or at least so we think. Plus, its fun to learn something new). The constraints are you cannot use a library to build your network. You can use libraries for pre-processing the data or for matrix operations. So we can use torch for the Tensor data structure, but none of its Models, if that makes sense.

Could you implement this by looping over weights rather than looping over output pixels? e.g. take a weight, multiply it by all pixels, shift it, and add to output. That would get this done in 33 trips to the GPU, rather than 397397 trips.

Your advice was very helpful. Thank you @NickODell.

Solution
Following Nick ODell's advice I altered the looping section to look like such:
        for i in range(conv1_weights.shape[0]):
            for j in range(conv1_weights.shape[1]):
                data_times_weight = conv1_weights[i, j] * data
                output += data_times_weight[i:i + output_height, j:j + output_width]
        output += conv1_bias[:output_height, :output_width]

This resulted in a massive speedup for both GPU and CPU:
0.028558707796037197
0.07935599982738495

